# RxJS do not throw error while mapping even when underlying observable throws error

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I have a network call where it's likely that api will throw an 400 error. I want to handle this gracefully.

Right now I do it like below -

```
   private fetchStatus(objectId: string): Observable<string> {
      return Observable.create((observer) => {
        this.http.get('/api/data-one').subscribe(response => {
          if (response.result === 'SUCCESS') {
              observer.next('SUCCESS');
          } else {
              observer.next('DENIED');
          }
          observer.complete();
        },
        error => {
          observer.next('DENIED');
          observer.complete();
        });
      });
  }
```

**But I will prefer doing it with Observable.map operator.** The problem with Observable.map is when api throws a 400 the entire observable goes in error mode.

I want to prevent this because this get call is being used in a forkJoin with other calls. Failure of this would mean failure of the entire forkJoin below

```
forkJoin([
        this.http.get('/api/route-2'),
        this.http.get('/api/route-1'),
        this.fetchStatus('abc')
      ]).subscribe((responseCollection: any) => {
        observer.next({
          result1: responseCollection[0],
          result2: responseCollection[1],
          result3: responseCollection[2]
        });
        observer.complete();
      }, error => observer.error(error));
```

Answer (score 2):

**You can do this with [map](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/map.html) and [catchError](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/error_handling/catch.html).**

`catchError` will catch any error thrown by the source and return a new Observable. This new Observable is what, in your case, will be passed to `forkJoin` in the case of a HTTP error.

```
private fetchStatus(objectId: string): Observable<string> {

    return this.http.get('/api/data-one').pipe(
        map(response => response.result === 'SUCCESS' ? 'SUCCESS' : 'DENIED'),
        catchError(error => of('DENIED')),
    );
  }
```